# Calling WCF service w/ ProtoBehavior and multiple parameters

Tags: wcf, protobuf-net

This one has me puzzled and am hoping it's a silly oversight on my part.  When I call the following web service, if a null parameter is encountered then all following parameters are null (or zero for the numerics).

```
[OperationContract, ProtoBehavior]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ServiceFault))]
[FaultContract(typeof(ServiceFault))]
PersonProfileMessagePart Create(ObjectId person, ObjectId industry, int yearsInIndustry, ObjectId occupation, string occupationFreeText,
                                int yearsInOccupation, string maritalStatus, string educationLevel, 
                                List<ChildMessagePart> children, FinancialProfileMessagePart financialProfile,
                                List<ObjectId> traits);
```

For example, if `person` and `yearsInIndustry` are present but not `industry`, all parameters including `yearsInIndustry` default to null/zero.  Is there an additional attribute I need to apply?

{edit}
My bad.  Marc, it is WCF with a custom binding.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceFedBinding">
        <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation">
            <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="IssuedToken">
                <issuedTokenParameters tokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1">
                    <issuer address="http://links-dev:91/security/authentication/securetokenservice.svc/" binding="wsHttpBinding">
                        <identity>
                            <dns value="LINKS"/>
                        </identity>
                    </issuer>
                    <issuerMetadata address="http://links-dev:91/security/authentication/securetokenservice.svc/mex"/>
                </issuedTokenParameters>
            </secureConversationBootstrap>
        </security>
```

Thanks in advance.
Mike

Comment: Can I confirm - is this using WCF? Any particular binding? Simply so I can try to reproduce it...